# When Binding how do I convert between datatypes?

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding

I am currently working out how to use XAML and how it interacts with C#. My current challenge is trying to get a textblock to change the text it displays when a checkbox is ticked. This requires the program to take a Bool input (is the box ticked?) and give a string output.

Currently when it runs the layout is correct making me suspect the XAML code is fine however the textblock will only display the "unticked" state whether the checkbox is ticked or not.

I suspect that the issue is between the two methods but I am unable find a solution, any suggestions?

The code in question : C#

```
public class MainPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
{   
    //stores value of checkbox  
    private bool _BoxCheckBool;

    //Updates value of _BoxCheckBool
    public bool BoxCheckBool
    {
        set
        {
            Set(ref _BoxCheckBool, value);
        }           
    }

    //stores value (for textblock) 
    private string _BoxCheckString;

    public string BoxCheckString
    {
        //logic that determines what will be sent to the textblock
        get
        {
            if (_BoxCheckBool == true)
            {
                _BoxCheckString = "The Box has been checked";
            }

            else if (_BoxCheckBool == false)
            {
                _BoxCheckString = "The Box has not been checked";
            }

            else
            {
                _BoxCheckString = "ERROR";
            }

            return _BoxCheckString;
        }

        set
        {
            Set(ref _BoxCheckString, value);
        }
    }
}
```

The code in question : XAML

```
    <CheckBox x:Name="BoxTest" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="Check Box" IsChecked="{Binding BoxCheckBool, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

    <TextBlock x:Name="BoxTestOutput" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding BoxCheckString, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Comment: Thank you everyone for your advice, it has been very helpful. :)

Answer (score 0):

You only need raise `PropertyChanged` event when `bool` property is changed.  UI will be updated automatically

```
public class MainPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
{   
    //stores value of checkbox  
    private bool _BoxCheckBool;

    //Updates value of _BoxCheckBool
    public bool BoxCheckBool
    {
        set
        {
            Set(ref _BoxCheckBool, value);
            // Assumes your ViewModelBase have method to raising this
            RaisePropertyChanged("BoxCheckString");
        }           
    }

    private string _BoxCheckString;

    public string BoxCheckString
    {
        //logic that determines what will be sent to the textblock
        get
        {
            if (_BoxCheckBool == true)
            {
                _BoxCheckString = "The Box has been checked";
            }
            else
            {
                _BoxCheckString = "The Box has not been checked";
            }
            // Boolean type have only two value (true/false) 
            // - you don't need checking for "errors"
            return _BoxCheckString;
        }
        set
        {
            Set(ref _BoxCheckString, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The text block did not updated because there was no notification when the value was changed.

To make a binding update, you need to implement [property change notification (Please check out this link)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695(v=vs.110).aspx). You need to call something like `OnPropertyChanged("BoxCheckString")` (depending on your `ViewModelBase`) inside the setter of `BoxCheckBool`, such that the text block knows that update is needed.

Comment: Ah, ok. Out of interest do I need to also tell the second method to check for updates or does the textblock referencing it automatically cause it to do so?

Comment: Just make sure that `PropertyChanged` event is raised for `BoxCheckString` after `BoxCheckString` is updated to the desired value, so the text block can get the most updated `BoxCheckString`. The text block will update automatically for each `PropertyChanged` event of `BoxCheckString`.

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the text value is wrong place:

ViewModel:

```
 private bool _BoxCheckBool;

    //Updates value of _BoxCheckBool
    public bool BoxCheckBool
    {
        get
        {
            return _BoxCheckBool;
        }
        set
        {
            _BoxCheckBool = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("BoxCheckBool");
            if (_BoxCheckBool == true)
            {
                BoxCheckString = "The Box has been checked";
            }

            else if (_BoxCheckBool == false)
            {
                BoxCheckString = "The Box has not been checked";
            }

            else
            {
                BoxCheckString = "ERROR";
            }
        }
    }

    //stores value (for textblock) 
    private string _BoxCheckString = "";

    public string BoxCheckString
    {
        //logic that determines what will be sent to the textblock
        get
        {
            return _BoxCheckString;
        }
        set
        { 
            _BoxCheckString = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("BoxCheckString");       
        }
    }
```

Xaml:

```
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <CheckBox Name="BoxTest" IsChecked="{Binding BoxCheckBool, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding BoxCheckString, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  />
    </StackPanel>
```